# Convert YYYY-YY to Year(date)

Tags: r, as.date

I have a data frame with year column as financial year

```
Year  
2001-02  
2002-03  
2003-04
```

How can I convert this to as.Date keeping either the whole thing or just the second year i.e 2002,2003,2004. On converting with `%Y`, I inevitably get 2001-08-08, 2002-08-08, 2003-08-08 etc.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use `sub('-.*', '', Year)` for the first year or `paste0('20', sub('.*-', '', '2001-02'))` for the second

Comment: `sub("^(..)..-(..)$", "\\1\\2", "2001-02")` for the second year.

Comment: Just don't use regular expressions for dates.  They will never catch things "April 31".  Only date parsers do, and we have many.  Use them, and recommend their use.

Comment: that gives me years starting 2001,2002,2003. I would require the second year to be the main.

Comment: on doing 
dat$Year <- year(dat$Year) + 1 it changes years to numeric and on converting back to %Y i get  dates like 1975-01-01

Comment: I actually never used regex on dates (never had to). What strike me to do it here is the `2001-2002` concept

Comment: it works with one individual 2001-02. What about the whole column. It's long. Cannot do this for every year value.

Comment: `sub` is vectorized, so will work over a vector of strings. For my answer, replace "2001-02" with the name of the vector object.

Comment: The problem remains - I use sub to convert it into 2001, 2002, 2003 but structure of the column remains as numeric. The moment I change into as.Date it again becomes 2001-01-01 and so on

Comment: Why are you using `as.Date`? This does not make sense as you do not have months or days. Both are necessary for the construction of a Date object.

Comment: Then how to make R understand it is a Year and not numeric?

Comment: I need R to understand that the column year is not numeric, but a date/time object as 2001 etc. Making a zoo object is not helping either.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)

Year <- c('2001-02', '2002-03', '2003-04')

year(as.Date(gsub('[0-9]{2}-', '', Year), format = '%Y'))
```

Comment: The str of the final column is numeric. I am looking for date format YYYY or YYYY-YY.

Comment: A date will always include the month and day. If you want only the year, you need to extract it as a number or character vector. That's what `year` from `lubridate` does, or you could just get it using `format`. AFAIK, you will not be able to get just the year and keep it in date type.

Answer (score 1):

**1) ISOdate** Clarifying the question, since it refers to yearend and Date we assume that the input is the fiscal Year shown in the question (plus we have added the "1999-00" edge case) as well as the month and day of the yearend.  We assume that the output desired is the yearend as a Date object.   (If that is not the intended question and you just want the fiscal yearend year as a number then see Note at the end.)

Returning to the assumed problem let us suppose, for example, that March 31st is the yearend. Below we extract the first 4 character of `Year` using `substring`, convert that to numeric and add 1.  Then we pass that along with month and day to `ISODate` and finally convert that to Date. No regular expressions or packages are used.

```
# test inputs

month <- 3
day <- 31
Year <- c("1999-00", "2001-02", "2002-03", "2003-04")

# yearends

as.Date(ISOdate( as.numeric(substring(Year, 1, 4))+1, month, day))
## [1] "2000-03-31" "2002-03-31" "2003-03-31" "2004-03-31"
```

**2) string manipulation** An alternative solution using the same inputs is the following. It is similar except that we use `sub` with a regular expression that matches the minus and following two characters subtituting a zero length string for them, converts to numeric and adds 1.  Then it formats a string in a format acceptable to `as.Date` by using `sprintf` and finally applies `as.Date`.  No packages are used.

```
as.Date(sprintf("%d-%d-%d", as.numeric(sub("-..", "", Year))+1, month, day))
## [1] "2000-03-31" "2002-03-31" "2003-03-31" "2004-03-31"
```

**Note:** If you only wanted the fiscal yearend year as a number then it would be just this:

```
as.numeric(substring(Year, 1, 4)) + 1
```